# Create JSON from keys of main JSON file

Tags: json, angularjs

I tried to get an array from JSON file keys.

My JSON file looks like this - http://prntscr.com/4j7jjh

So, in *app.js* file I got data from JSON file, but cannot now to create an array only from `{{key}}` data (in my case in "parametres")..

```
$http.get('buttons.json')
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.buttonStyles = res.data;

        console.log($scope.buttonStyles.parametres);
});
```

Created array should looks like:

- padding
- width

I tried to use `angular.fromJson(json);` but did not get how to use it.

Thank you

Comment: can you show how look your $scope.buttonStyles now? pase console.log here

Comment: can you paste the end result that you desire for?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4j7n68

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need this.
This will create an array of objects with padding and width parameters.

```
var len = res.data;
var arr = []
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
   var obj = {};
   obj.padding = res.data[i]["parametres"]["padding"];
   obj.width = res.data[i]["parametres"]["width"];
   arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
$http.get('buttons.json')
    .then(function(res){
      var result = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++){
        result.push(res.data[i]["parametres"]);
      }

      $scope.buttonStyles = result;

      console.log($scope.buttonStyles);
});
```